# MySQL 3.23 UNION fails with Error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to use a UNION statement in an old BugZilla MySQL DB running MySQL 3.23.  Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do.  It's really nothing exotic but MySQL keeps saying that something is wrong.

```
(select bug_id,rep_platform from bugs where rep_platform='XX') 
 UNION 
(select bug_id,rep_platform from bugs where rep_platform='YY');
```

The result I get is:

```
ERROR 1064 (HY000): You have an error in your SQL syntax near '(select bug_id,rep_platform from bugs where rep_platform='XX')
UNION
(select bu' at line 1
```

This is really about as simple of a union statement as you can get.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  I ran a very similar query on a MySQL 5 DB and it worked just fine.  Is these some special UNION syntax on MySQL 3 that doesn't show up in documentation or Google searches?

Comment: You need two things. Please look in my answer. I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the UNION is not working in MySQL 3 is because MySQL 3 does not support UNION statements :) Take a look at the official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/union.html).

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set. UNION is available from MySQL 4.0.0 on.

Take a look at this [article](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Database-Articles/Writing-UNION-statements-in-MySQL-3x/) for workarounds.

Comment: Wow, it was right in front of my eyes.  The documentation I was reading was 3.23, 4.0, 4.1 Reference Manual (Chapter 12.2.7.3) on UNION syntax.  There's a small blurb in there that says that UNION is supported in 4.0 and higher that I completely missed.  Thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bug_id, rep_platform
    FROM bugs
    WHERE rep_platform IN ('XX', 'YY');
```

Comment: And if `bug_id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, you could also skip the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I was simplifying.  The actual query is more complicated.  The query I posted should work but doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

```
select bug_id,rep_platform from bugs A where rep_platform='XX'
UNION  
select bug_id,rep_platform from bugs where rep_platform='YY';
```

Joe's answer is much easier and pleasing on the eyes. +1 for Joe.

The two changes I made are

1. I dropped all parentheses
2. I put a table alias A next to bugs in the first SELECT

Comment: You shouldn't need a sub query but either way, I copied and pasted and still get the same error.