# Syntax error in MySQL near UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

```
SELECT * 
FROM Activity AA
WHERE AA.act_id IN 
((SELECT A.act_id 
  FROM Activity A 
  WHERE A.user_id = 'lhfcws')
 UNION
 (SELECT J.act_id 
  FROM Joinin J 
  WHERE J.user_id = 'lhfcws'))
ORDER BY AA.act_time
```

> ERROR MESSAGE:
>   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near `'UNION (SELECT J.act_id FROM Joinin J WHERE J.user_id =
>   'lhfcws')) ORDE' at line 7`

Activity(act_id, user_id, act_name)
Joinin(act_id, user_id)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL 3.23 UNION fails with Error 1064](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202667/mysql-3-23-union-fails-with-error-1064)

Comment: That duplicate does not have a satisfactory [accepted] answer; this one does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, don't think you need such a subquery

```
select * from Activity a
where a.user_id = 'lhfcws'
and exists (select null from Joinin j
where a.user_id = j.user_id);
```

sould do the same

maybe you need one more check

```
select * from Activity a
    where a.user_id = 'lhfcws'
    and exists (select null from Joinin j
    where a.user_id = j.user_id
    and a.act_id = j.act_id);
```

Acording to @Jonathan Leffler's (true) remark

```
select * from Activity a
        where a.user_id = 'lhfcws'
        or exists (select null from Joinin j
        where j.user_id = 'lhfcws'
        and a.act_id = j.act_id);
```

Comment: UNION is an OR; do you mean OR EXISTS?

Comment: wow~!it works! thx a lot ~~but i still wonder why i was wrong~~

Answer (score 8):

The reason for your error is the parens around the select statements. You should write it as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Activity AA
WHERE AA.act_id IN 
(SELECT A.act_id 
  FROM Activity A 
  WHERE A.user_id = 'lhfcws'
 UNION
 SELECT J.act_id 
  FROM Joinin J 
  WHERE J.user_id = 'lhfcws')
ORDER BY AA.act_time
```

But do go over @Raphaël Althaus ideas for improving your query.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ORDER BY` before **UNION**